# Convert string to DateTime using special format

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I convert this string to a `DateTime`:

```
string t = "2017-02-20 13h24m18s";
```

The format is: XXXX-XX-XX XXhXXmXXs

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8) to parse the string using a specific format:

```
string t = "2017-02-20 13h24m18s";

if(DateTime.TryParseExact(t, @"yyyy-MM-dd HH\hmm\mss\s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, out var dt))
{
    // parsed successfully into dt
}
```

Just be sure to escape `13h` as `HH\h`, `24m` as `mm\m` and `18s` as `ss\s`.

Comment: If this solved your question, could you please accept it as the answer, so others know that this issue is resolved? [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace values easily before converting

```
static public DateTime todate(string t)
{
    t = t.Replace("h", ":");
    t = t.Replace("m", ":");
    t = t.Replace("s", "");
    return DateTime.Parse(t);
}
```

now use

```
string test = "2017-02-20 13h2m18s";
DateTime a = todate(test);
```